# Google Cloud Datastore - What is the correct syntax to filter by Key in the Developer Console?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to query for an entity User in a Google cloud datastore with a key, using Googles developers console query filter. (Google Cloud Developer Console -> Cloud Datastore -> Query)

[image]

I fail to decipher the example syntax and am always prompted with the following error message:

`Error: Keys for datastore operations must be in the format Key('kind0', 'name0'/id0, 'kind1', 'name1'/id1, ...)`

On appengine.google.com I used to query for a specific key on a User like this:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE __key__ = Key('User','XXXXX')
```

I tried `Key('User','XXXXX')` in the Google developers console but was always pointed to the error message above. Any ideas what the correct syntax would be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parser seems to be overly strict. As a workaround, you can add a space between the arguments to Key():

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE __key__ = Key('User', 'XXXXX')
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Add a space after the comma. This wasn't required at the old console at http://appengine.google.com but is at the new one at console.cloud.google.com

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of the key? Using Key('User', ) should work on the console. I tried here and it worked for an Entity named person with a numeric id. I used Key('Person',1).