# What is the correct syntax to filter by 'Key' in the Developer Console for Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417374/google-cloud-datastore-what-is-the-correct-syntax-to-filter-by-key-in-the-deve) is an old question on this topic, now it has new problem.

Update:
Google update its console and this problem is solved. The right format is `"Key('$YOUR_KIND'," + " " + $YOUR_VALUE + ")"`. Please note that there must be only one space after comma, if your key is number then just write it, for example: `Key('my_kind', 1234567890)`, String type key need be quoted, for example: `Key('MyKind', 'test_01')`.

Original question.
`Key('MyKind', 1)` does not work, it shows `Your request included invalid parameters` without any meaningful information, I have to catch the network response and get the detail error description `__key__ filter namespace is  but query namespace is test01`. Notice that there are two spaces between "... namespace is" and "but query ...", seems that I should add namespace in the key. Does anyone know how to add it or some other way to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM Kind where __key__ = KEY('Kind', <id or name>)
```

So your example of Key('MyKind', 1) should have KEY as uppercase. If you're using ids, then 1 is ok, if you're using names (i.e. strings) you must quote it.

Comment: Let me clarify that "Key('MyKind', 1)" is used in console with "Query by kind", KEY-like way is not working. Another problem is that if I use "Query using GQL", it should be "KEY(MyKind, 1)" without quotation marks around kind name. BTW, I cannot get any result with GQL even I just use select * from MyKind without filter or use an existed KEY as the condition. It is so weird.

Comment: [You can read about GQL grammar here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference#grammar). As you can see there's a syntax for declaring the namespace of the entity key. You can read more about the KEY syntax at [this specific part](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference#synthetic_literals) of that page. Finally, if you're going to say "X is not working", you'd better post what X is, in terms of the literal query, and also *in what way* it "doesn't work". This is how programmers narrow down how to solve a problem, with specific details. Good luck!

Comment: @anonymous4444 Thank you for these information, I find the way to use specific namespace in GQL. In this question I concern: a) why google console do not show some useful error like a compiler, now they update and have it. b) why using their recommand format still do not work, now they fix it. This is the key point. c) Why "select * from MyKind" return nothing? Now they remove the function of "Query using GQL" in console.

Comment: You can simply click on the "Filters" button and use the UI. It forms GQL behind the scenes anyway, so if you select in the dropdowns until you have something like "[Key] is [a key] [that is] Key('kind0', 'name0'/id0, ...), you can specify the ancestor path to build the key just the same as you did in GQL.